# How to get actual values from timer in C#

Tags: c#, timer, console-application

I've problem with creating timer in C# console application that not only shows elapsing time but also returns value of that time. I need it to calculate velocity of moving sensor, which frame I get and convert into real distance it traveled. Unfortunately I can't do that with timer from System.Threading, because it returns void.

Is there a possibility to do such thing or should I use stopwatch to get value of time between each answer of sensor and then return value of time as sum of current intervals?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Stopwatch. Timer is designed for triggering events at intervals. The other problem is that it is possible for the duration of the assigned task at each interval to exceed the interval itself, which will cause the timer interval to vary between consecutive calls.

Stopwatch will provide a relatively high-resolution timer that can be used to measure elapsed time whenever you need it, with much higher accuracy than Timer.

You can calculate the velocity using the Stopwatch with code similar to this:

```
Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
watch.Start();

// your code here
double distanceInMeters = GetDistanceFromSensor();

double velocity = distanceInMeters / (watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0);
```